# Can I use an OS X Swift source file in an iOS game or can I remake it as an iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I accidently created an OS X source file for an iOS game I am creating. Is there anyway I can turn the OS X Swift source file to an iOS without having to recreate a new iOS swift source file?  Can an OS X file work on an iOS platform game/app?

Comment: Writing code for two hours without pressing compile once sounds like an excellent idea.

Comment: I did press compile. I just didnt put that on there sorry. I press compile literally every 10 minutes so there you have it.

Comment: And even at this point, you couldn't tell the difference between an iOS and OS X application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.... The source file doesn't make a difference. It's just a template for creating an AppKit or UIKit base class. If you didn't inherit your class from anything it doesn't matter..... Just ensure your Swift class inherits from the proper class in UIKit (unless it's a base class that doesn't inherit from anything) and you should be fine.